# Does SendJobs extract include in progress throttled sends?

Tags: email, reporting, tracking-extract

Per the help documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sendjobs.htm&type=5), the SendJobs extract should include jobs with a status of 'Sending.' In an account, I had a job that was throttled over two days but was only included in a SendJobs extract once the job completed sending. Is this expected behavior?

Background on timing:

- Email job initiated sending at 4pm CT on Day 1
- Email completed sending at 12:11am CT on Day 1
- Tracking extract (which includes SendJobs for the previous day) ran at 1am CT on Day 2. The affected email was not part of this extract.
- Tracking extract that ran on Day 3 included the affected email from Day 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFMC Support indicated that even though their documentation shows a number of potential values for the 'JobStatus' column of the SendJobs extract, that said extract is only coded to populate with either 'Pending,' 'Complete,' 'Error,' or 'Canceled.' When asked if the Job Data View uses the same logic to populate the 'JobStatus' column I was told that it (the Job Data View) and the Extract both populate from 'TblJobs' on the backend and will display the same results with the above outputs.

Needless to say this is an opportunity (as of Sept 2020) for SFMC to update the official documentation.